# Add file extension to variable

Tags: c#

I am new to c sharp
can anybody say what the mistake

```
string cPict= "Picture\"+firstSelectedItem+".jpg";
```

where

- "Picture\" = folder
- firstSelectedItem = Employee Number
- ".jpg" = file extension

getting following error

> string does not contain definition for  jpg

please help

thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to post a clear and precise question containing your actual code. As it stands, it's unclear what exactly you are asking.

Comment: alternatively use \\ instead of \

Comment: string cPict= @"Picture\"+firstSelectedItem+".jpg";

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in `"\"+firstSelectedItem` all is treated as string, even the `firstSelectedItem` variable because you've used the [`\`-character to escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) the following `"`.

You either have to

1. escape the `\`-character by another one,
2. use a verbatim string literal or
3. use the [`Path`-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx), especially `Path.Combine`:

1)

```
string cPict = "Picture\\" + firstSelectedItem + ".jpg";
```

2)

```
string cPict = @"Picture\" + firstSelectedItem + ".jpg";
```

3)

```
string cPict = Path.Combine("Picture", firstSelectedItem + ".jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with normal slash like that:

```
string cPict= "Picture/"+firstSelectedItem+".jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

The \ is a special character that escapes the next character in a string, therefore, according to the compiler then + firstSelectedItem + is still part of the string. Your code should look like one of the following:

```
 string cPict = @"Picture\" +
```

or:

```
 string cPict = "Picture\\" +
```

and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the backslash \ character

```
string cPict= "Picture\\"+firstSelectedItem+".jpg";
```

learn about [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) here

Comment: Or use verbatim string literal: `string cPict=@"Picture\"+firstSelectedItem+".jpg";`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add double slashes as below:

```
string cPict= "Picture\\"+firstSelectedItem+".jpg";

"Picture\\"=folder
```